# Oracle VirtualBox connecting USB device

Tags: usb, virtualbox

Oracle VirtualBox (v 4.3.4 r 91027) installed on Windows 7 64-bit throws this error message:

```
Failed to attach USB device STMicroelectronics STM32 STLink[0100] to the virtual machine ..
.. is busy with previous request..
```

Comment: Can you provide the log file for Virtual Box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a device filter as mentioned by rubStackOverflow is necessary avoid the host OS using actual drivers for the device. If you got this right and watch the Windows Device Manager while plugging in the device, you see `USB Controllers -> Virtualbox USB` appearing instead of the actual device.

If then the device is not detected by the guest OS, check if the host Windows has an upper USB filter driver like `USBPcap` installed. (Reference: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=39104#p176270)

1. Start regedit.
2. Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}`.
3. Look for a key `UpperFilters`. In my case it was there and had value `USBPcap`. Most likely this came from Wireshark or I may have installed it manually.
4. Rename or remove the key `UpperFilters`.
5. Reboot the host.
6. Check the USB filter setting of the guest (generalize it by leaving everything clear except VID/PID settings).
7. Start guest.
8. Plug in USB device.
9. Watch host device manager show Virtualbox USB.

   10. Watch guest device manager detect actual device.

Good luck!

Comment: Visit the link. There's a missing step.  You have to go to C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\USB\filter and reinstall the VBoxUSBMon.inf file.  Other than that it still works (Windows 10 64-bit host, Linux guest) - August 2016.

Comment: In my case, there was `UsbDk` in `UpperFilters`, making all attempts to pass USB devices through to VirtualBox fail. A lot of thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to add your device and a device filter.

1. Install the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" to match your VirtualBox version. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. Connect your USB device.
3. Confirm that you can also see your USB device via the VBoxManage list usbhost command. You cannot add a working Filter in VirtualBox until this is working.
4. In VirtualBox, go to the Settings of your guest, USB section, and add a Filter for your USB device and a new device filter (empty).
5. Start your guest and confirm that it can see your device.

(This steps I get from here: superuser.com/questions/306172/how-can-i-make-my-virtualbox-vista-see-my-usb-device-ipad)

Here the video that illustrates step by step, how I fix this problem:
[USB device is busy with a previous request](http://youtu.be/mS_cyIgLuFU)

Credit to: youtube.com/user/tutorialnacional

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please edit your answer to include the actual steps to fix the problem, such that when/if the linked article is no longer available your answer is still useful to others.  You are still of course encouraged to give credit to the linked source.

Comment: Edited and complemented

Answer (score 0):

As I spent some time googling the answer, here is what helped me out:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=59303

> I've done a lot of changes. I'm not sure what step did the fix.
>
> I changed my VM a little bit, I moved it from C: to D:, and added a CPU in VirtualBox settings. Then I made a change in the Device Manager of the host machine. Yesterday I tried out the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" of the "Power Management" of both Generic USB Hubs with no breakthrough, today I unmarked that again on both Generic USB Hubs. I also deleted parts of the USB Filter (but I tried that before many times) and finally I started my VM again.
>
> After I inserted the USB device I got a notification from my host that it installed the VirtualBox driver! (I don't know if it installed it again?!) Then I could bind the USB device by right-clicking the USB icon of the VM window and selecting the device.
>
> Yes, that was the problem, the VirtualBox USB driver was missing from Universal Serial Bus controllers. I don't know how, but I could bind a USB stick.

Comment: Welcome to SU. While your link might provide the answer it can quickly before outdated or removed. Can you include the main information from the link in which answers the question in your answer and provide the link as a source. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I daily run 3~4 Virtual machines, XP and Win7, under Win 8 Host, with hibernation;
these use a few Sandisk USB, some of them partitioned and readable only inside the XPsp2 environment; nowhere else.
It's so easy to find them "busy with a Previous Request "… that it triggers something like a domino effect, even rebooting the system.
So some structured jobs are unable to proceed anyhow.
No UpperFilters entry to remove from the Registry; after years of vain hope, here is my only solution, rudimentary but drastic, to escape this nightmare.

Suppose this [Sandisk] case.

VBox:
Remove any single device from the USB Setting of ALL your Virtual machines.

System:
Unplug all the attached USB using the system's function: "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" icon for "Open Devices and Printers", or something alike, (I generally suggest not to simply use the "Eject" by the explorer menu).
Close the VM Oracle Virtualbox.

Now find and delete from the Registry ALL occurrences of Sandisk [in my case, or any USB in use] - you can even export them before, but there is no risk to do that at this point, provided you know exactly what you are doing.
I don't give details, since you should know what I am speaking about. Note that I found 172 [HKEY_… references to remove, so you will probably need a tool to do that.
Restart the system to clean up.

Reset:
Open the VM Oracle Virtualbox.
Plug one USB (at a time), select and set into one machine (at a time) the appropriate USB.
Run that machine and ensure the USB is mounted: it must also disappear from the Host system Explorer.
Do not overlap the same USB in different Vbox.

This is plain, but it's eventually working for me.
*Do not give familiarity to the computer, always treat it like a stupid ('cause that's it):* one thing at A TIME.
Forgive my English.

---

By the way, I have another 'Virtual' problem, i.e. I cannot run any machine by "Show" without meeting another ugly infinite error, that hangs everything for a long time and no solution: no machine can start.
Sorry, it is out of topic, but it could help somebody as well.
I can't reproduce it now (I'm working and such an attempt would compromise everything…) but it's known and I could'nt find any solution.

Note that I cannot evenly reinstall Virtual Machine, due to another Windows gift, the famous "Error Code 2755" (especially for Virtualbox only - I could install some other apps)
I cannot evenly reinstall Windows and a lot of other things, for my time is precious and I don't have a week to burn down this way.
But I found how to escape this too: open the Start [click the down arrow] menu and select 'Headless Start": the machine starts hidden and in a few seconds the command arrow will be green again. Then click it to follow the Normal view startup.